# Microsoft Bot Framework with Dynamics365. Different tenants

Tags: azure, botframework, dynamics-365, azure-bot-service

I have developed a bot with Bot-Framework and it is integrated with Bot Service in Azure subscription account and when I try to connect it with Dynamics365 I can't see the option to add this bot because Dynamics365 is in another tenant. Is there a way to connect them?
Thanks.

Comment: Linking your GitHub question, and its associated answer, for visibility: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6454#issuecomment-1018068788

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested in lab, but exporting or importing a Bot Solution to another Tenant, will be one of the solution.

Reference Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/authoring-export-import-bots